# AngularJS - Controller not registered with ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, oclazyload, lazy-loading

I've just implemented ocLazyLoad to my site, however I have a problem that even though the module is being loaded correctly (according to debug anyway) but the Controller apparently still doesnt exist.

application.js:
I deleted oc.lazyload from there since it LazyLoads it now (at least I think? When I had it in there but the JS files weren't loaded yet I got module error so..).

routing.js (config file):
app.config(['$routeProvider', "$locationProvider",'$translateProvider', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider)

{

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
         debug: true,
         modules: [
         {
                name: 'ui.tinymce',
                files: [
                        '../controller/tinymce/tinymce.js',
                        '../controller/angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js',
                        '../../assets/js/app.js?v=140'
                        ]
                }
                ,{
                name: 'smoothScroll',
                files: [
                            '../../assets/js/angular-smooth-scroll.js?v=2'
                        ]
    }]
    });
```

...

```
        route: '/Support/Ticket/',
        templateUrl: templatePath + "support" + "/ticket.html",
        resolve: {
        eventCtrl: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load(
          {
            files: ['app/controller/tinymce/tinymce.js',
                        'app/controller/angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js',
                        'assets/js/app.js?v=140']
          });
      }
    }
```

When visiting the web page it gives me this debug info:

```
ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded app/controller/angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js
angular.js?v=4:344 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded assets/js/app.js?v=140
angular.js?v=4:344 ocLazyLoad.fileLoaded app/controller/tinymce/tinymce.js
angular.js?v=4:344 ocLazyLoad.componentLoaded (3) ["ui.tinymce", "value", "uiTinymceConfig"]
angular.js?v=4:344 ocLazyLoad.componentLoaded (3) ["ui.tinymce", "directive", "uiTinymce"]
angular.js?v=4:344 ocLazyLoad.componentLoaded (3) ["ui.tinymce", "service", "uiTinymceService"]
angular.js?v=4:344 ocLazyLoad.moduleLoaded ui.tinymce
```

And AFTER the debug Info I get this:

```
The controller with the name 'TinyMceController' is not registered.
```

Any Idea how to fix it? If information is missing please tell.

Best regards,
Konst

Comment: Why are you using lazyload for your controller?  That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I don't want TinyMCE to be loaded at site visit. What doesn't make sense here?

Comment: controllers get instantiated each time you visit a route so lazyload doesn't make much sense for a controller.

Comment: I want TinyMCE JS files and controller to load only when the ticket system is being visited. How do I do that? I mean it's a general problem, I can't use the .load function within my routing config. Any idea why?